# ASP.NET MVC Web Application Vs Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I've created a ASP.NET MVC Web Application, and when I right click on it in the solution explorer of VS2012, it shows me an option of convert into web application. What does that mean? Didn't I already create a MVC Web Application. Please explain

Answer (score 3):

That's clearly a bug in Visual Studio. Ignore this option. When you create a new ASP.NET MVC application it is already a Web Application (in contrast to a WebSite). By the way once you click on that option it only asks you to confirm and it remains there after.

Comment: I see. I thought so. Thanks for the answer.